# What is the easiest way of getting Delphi to accept a newly added file as a frame and to treat it as such?

Tags: delphi, frame

Especially as there are a number of new releases of Delphi these days it can be beneficial to simply take a project that is a 'few' Delphi releases old and recreate the *.dproj file. There is so much in the project dproj file now that unexplained behaviour, especially with mobile targets, can often be cured by 'starting again'. This is quite easy in principle - create a new 'empty' project of the type that you want (VCL or Multi-device project), and then add in your old files dragging and dropping on to the new project in the project tree view. This works fine for normal units and forms but seems to fall down with frames because the project does not recognise dropped frames in the same way as if you had used 'New...Delphi..Frame' in the IDE. It has been this way ever since EMB introduced FireMonkey I think, and there are fixes. My question is about the easiest way of getting around this 'Frame blindness'. These solutions seem to work (but are messy):

1. In the new project, create a 'New' 'Frame' as intended and rename it to your existing 'old' file. Delete the new empty frame from disk and replace it with your old file (changing the name where necessary). Messy - it is easy to forget to keep the component name in track.
2. Drag a drop the frame units in the normal way, they will get treated as forms and you will get errors from the forms that require those frames. Close the project, then manually edit the dproj file using the suggestion [here](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.ide/in-xe4-all-frames-are-ignored-for-inse/1062441)

change:

> ```
> <DCCReference Include="x\y\z\myFrame.pas">
>  <Form>frameMy</Form> 
> <DesignClass>TFrame</DesignClass>
> </DCCReference>
> ```

to:

> ```
> <DCCReference Include="x\y\z\myFrame.pas">
>  <Form>frameMy</Form> 
> **<FormType>dfm</FormType>**
>  <DesignClass>TFrame</DesignClass>
>  </DCCReference>
> ```

Does anyone have a nicer solution? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why not write a small app to automate the process. A simple XML parser should do the job.....

Comment: @Johan: Yes, that's a good idea.

Comment: Project Magician has an option for doing that.
https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2018/05/17/keep-your-project-files-clean-with-project-magician/